# PHP pre-built classes like PDO and stdClass auto-include elucidation

Tags: php, include, require, include-path

Hi everyone I just have some doubts about php include. I have checked my phpinfo(); output and saw that my include_path is 'php/lib/php'.

I would like to know how PHP loads a pre built class e.g. the PDO class definition or a 'stdClass' when I instantiate it in my script without using any include or require statement. How PHP handles it?

Does it use an include statement or a require? Where does it find the classes (cause I searched in the php/lib/php directory and didn't find any file that reminds something about 'PDO' or 'stdClass').

I am just curious to understand this PHP mechanism cause I would like to know if I put e.g. a file 'MyClass.class.php' in the 'php/lib/php' directory, will PHP auto-include it when I instantiate a new MyClass(); object in my script (thus without calling any include or require statement at the start of the script)?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about writing an [autoloader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), here. You may be interested in the [PSR-0 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

Comment: So even for the PDO and stdClass there's a pre-built PHP autoloader?